# K. 397 different versions

Tags: piano, mozart, slurs, editions

When looking for this score I see slightly different versions in terms of phrasing/slurs.

Bars 7-12 for example here

vs

Is the 2nd version the 'urtext' aka original/least edited version?
cause I would prefer to have the original and embellish from there.

Comment: Have you had a look at [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Fantasia_in_D_minor,_K.397/385g_(Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus))?

Answer (score 2):

The Walter Gieseking video uses the 1982 Bärenreiter Urtext edition, edited by Wolfgang Plath for the *Neue Mozart-Ausgabe*.

The edition can be found on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Fantasia_in_D_minor,_K.397/385g_(Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus)#Scores).

Answer (score 2):

Both the corresponding volume (NMA IX/27/2) and critical commentary of the *Neue Mozart Ausgabe* are freely available online [here](https://dme.mozarteum.at/DME/nma/start.php?l=2). This edition corresponds to the score given in the second video.

As for the precise issue at hand, the only comment about ties and slurs given in either the critical commentary or the preface concerns the ties in mes. 1-6 (which are seemingly - erroneously - omitted in the first posthumous edition, which if one were to follow literally would in this instance give a "bizarre effect" by giving an accent on a weak beat [NMA IX/27/2, p. XVI]). Given that presence of such (which are in fact rather uncommon in sources from this period, to say the least) elsewhere would surely be indicated, it indeed seems that the additional slurs in mes. 7-12 are very much that specific editor's opinion. One must however note that is not a bad suggestion, though, as the editor of the NMA volume indicates in the preface that a nearly legatissimo approach would be self-evident here ([op. cit.]: "*Im Sinne der zeitgenössischen Aufführungspraxis ist annähernd Legatissimo-Vortrag selbstverständlich.*").